# How to replace a single number from a comma separated string in oracle using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have the following set of data where I need to replace the number 41 with another number.

**column1**

41,46

31,41,48,55,58,121,122 

31,60,41

41

We can see four conditions here
41,
41
,41,
41,

I have written the following query

```
REGEXP_replace(column1,'^41$|^41,|,41,|,41$','xx')
```

where xx is the number to be replaced.
This query will replace the comma as well which is not expected.

**Example** : **41,46** is replaced as **xx46**. Here the expected output is **xx,46**. Please note that there are no spaced between the comma and numbers.

Can somebody help out how to use the regex?

Comment: Why are you storing your data in such a CSV format?  As you can see, it makes it very hard to work with and maintain your data.  Much better it would be to have each number in the CSV list on a separate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the string is comma separated, You can use comma concatenation with `replace` and `trim` to do the replacement. No regex needed. You should avoid regex as the solution is likely to be slow.

```
with t (column1) as (
    select '41,46'                  from dual union all
    select '31,41,48,55,58,121,122' from dual union all
    select '31,60,41'               from dual union all
    select '41'                     from dual
)
-- Test data setup. Actual solution is below: --

select
    column1,
    trim(',' from replace(','||column1||',', ',41,', ',17,')) as replaced
from t;
```

Output:

```
COLUMN1                 REPLACED
41,46                   17,46
31,41,48,55,58,121,122  31,17,48,55,58,121,122
31,60,41                31,60,17
41                      17

4 rows selected.
```

Also, it's worth noting here that the comma separated strings is **not** the right way of storing data. Normalization is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.